# Earth magnetic field, WMM/IGRF

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, dipole, dipole-moment

I am studying about World Magnetic Model (WMM) and International Geomagnetic Reference Field (IGRF) models. It is well known that, to a first approximation, earth magnetic field is a field of dipole. It corresponds to the first term in the Gaussian series. Is it possible to estimate the error of such an approximation? I am interested only in dipole approximation, i. e. is it possible to obtain an error of given (first) Gauss coefficient, or is there any studies where the dipole model investigated, with estimation of uncertainties?

Comment: If you don't get good answers here, you could also try this question on [EarthScience.SE].